# java.lang.double error - React Native (issue in android only)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, apk

Error: "**java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String**"
This error doesn't occur when we install and run .ipa file but it throws this error for android. And I don't even know which part of my React Native code is it throwing the error for!!!
Can someone please help me to find which part of my code is throwing this error??
 How to debug this??

Comment: Have you added any package recently?

Comment: no package added

Comment: please elaborate on any new packages you have added / when have you recieved this error

Comment: check the logcat in android studio or add sentry to ur react native project its the best for figure out what can be the problem

Comment: Is the error code point out where the issue from?